# Swift - time based UUID - how to sort them

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, datetime, uuid

I am creating and using time base UUID for items. I am using this function:

```
  class func timeBasedUUID() -> NSUUID {
    let uuidSize = sizeof(uuid_t)
    let uuidPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.alloc(uuidSize)
    uuid_generate_time(uuidPointer)
    let uuid = NSUUID(UUIDBytes: uuidPointer)
    uuidPointer.dealloc(uuidSize)
    return uuid
  }
```

And now I would like to know how can I sort them from oldest to newest. I was thinking about comparing strings but it is correct? Because I don't think so.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to get timestamp back from this?

Comment: KSUIDs are best for this type of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UUIDs have no "oldest" or "newest" component. It's true that `uuid_generate_time` uses the time to help guarantee *uniqueness*, but it is not intended as a way of actually recording the time. Don't try to misuse it in this way. If you know you're going to need to sort items by date, you need to give them an additional bit of information, e.g. a timestamp.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that when I use time based uuid It can be reverse to get time.

Comment: That's confusing. After all, in Java for instance it is a basic method of (re-) generating the timestamp from a uuid. Do you have any source for this statement?

Comment: @matt, Is there anyway to fetch timestamp from UUID similar to Java?

Comment: It is wrong. There are uuid1 and uuid7 time sortable version of uuid

Answer (score 1):

Decoding timestamp from UUIDv1 in swift:

```swift
extension UUID {
    static func timeBasedUUID() -> UUID? {
        let uuidSize = MemoryLayout<uuid_t>.size
        let uuidPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: uuidSize)
        uuid_generate_time(uuidPointer)
        let uuid = uuidPointer.withMemoryRebound(to: uuid_t.self, capacity: 1) {
            return $0.pointee
        }

        uuidPointer.deallocate()
        return UUID(uuid: uuid)
    }

    var timestamp: TimeInterval {
        let components = uuidString.split(separator: "-")
        assert(components.count == 5)
        let hex = String(components[2].dropFirst()) + components[1] + components[0]
        // 100-nanoseconds intervals
        let interval = Int(hex, radix: 16)!
        let seconds = TimeInterval(interval / 10000000)

        // -12219292800 relative seconds to 1970
        return seconds - 12219292800
    }
}
```

references:

- [Extracting the date and time a UUID was created](https://dabblingwithdata.wordpress.com/2018/10/13/extracting-the-date-and-time-a-uuid-was-created-with-bigquery-sql-with-a-brief-foray-into-the-history-of-the-gregorian-calendar/)
- [how do i get the date/time back from a UUID type 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51124223/1135154)
- [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address))